# Priniting to HTML Table using a python list

Tags: python, list, html-table

I have a python list which I imported from a CSV and I have sorted the data but know I need to find out how can I convert my list to a html table output. T

```
import csv

with open('bike_results.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
  bike_list = list(reader)

print(bike_list)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data would help !

Comment: you have to give details of CSV files means column name and row. So that Columns names will go in Table Head and rows will go in Table Body.

Comment: I'm really stuck in how to do that this why I'm asking

Comment: I understand that it needs to be filtered throught the table but I would like to do this without a long piece of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please find the below code for your query by assuming the first line is the header for your HTML table

```
import csv

with open('results.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ',
                    quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    bike_list = list(reader)
    html_content = "<html><body><table><tr><td>" + bike_list[0][0] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][1] + "</td></tr>"
i=1
while i < len(bike_list):
    html_content += "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(bike_list[i][0],bike_list[i][1])
    i+=1
html_content += "</table></body></html>"
```

print html_content